# Google Apps free no longer, custom domain on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps

Now that Google Apps will no longer have a free account, will we need to pay Google to be able to use custom domains on Google App Engine?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about payment plans for third party services.

Comment: I do not agree that this question is off topic. It helped me find out why my custom-domain worked for 30 days and then stopped working without notice.

Comment: For the benefit of others who might find this: Reading all the way through the post by Lawrence Mok below, you'll find that as of April 2014 you can now configure a custom domain without Google Apps, using the Developers Console (select the app, then go to App Engine -> Settings).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[update 2015-09-28]
Now Google lets you add custom domains and setup SSL without the need of Google Apps. For details refer to here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/using-custom-domains-and-ssl?hl=en

<del>Update...all the free lunch are over!</del>

<del>The announcement itself is here - https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-appengine/jC_K-YlmXhM</del>

Answer (score 6):

Actually, adding a custom domain on Google App Engine is a workaround to still get a free Google Apps account. I havn't tried, but according to [this link](http://www.labnol.org/internet/google-apps-free/26926/) it's working. You can try for yourself and see.

Comment: This answer is no longer correct.

Answer (score 1):

It's still free if you've already created the account.

Comment: not very useful for those who haven't